# Webpack handlebars-loader temaplate file does not resolve in mocha unit test

Tags: node.js, webpack, handlebars.js

I am using `handlebars-loader` to use handlebar templates with webpack.

I have the following code structure. I am able to build code using webpack but when I run mocha unit tests the handlebar template fails to resolve.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Rest of webpack.config.js 

    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.handlebars$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" }
      ]
    };
};
```

**index.ts**

```
import EmailTemplate from './templates/email.handlebars';

export const handler = async (event, _context) => {

    let emailResponse = EmailTemplate({ code: '123' });
   
    return emailResponse;
};
```

***Error when running unit tests***

```
Cannot find module './templates/email.handlebars' or its corresponding type declarations.
import EmailTemplate from './templates/email.handlebars';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run unit test after requiring `handlebars-loader` while running unit test command.

Also converted `import` to `require` while using handlebars templates in code.

**index.ts**

```
const EmailTemplate = require('./templates/email.handlebars');

export const handler = async (event, _context) => {

    let emailResponse = EmailTemplate({ code: '123' });
   
    return emailResponse;
};
```

And while running mocha test added ***--require handlebars-loader***

```
node_modules/.bin/_mocha  --require ts-node/register --require handlebars-loader  functionName/test/**/*.spec.ts
```